# binance historical data

Tags: python, websocket, cryptoapi

```
async def subscribe_quote(pair, rates_dict, hit_ready_amount=0, hit_ready_quantity=0):
    ws_url = 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws'
    while True:
        end_time = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=12)
        is_got_full_orderbook = False
        subscribe_id = int(time.time() * 100000)
        last_update_id = None
        prev_event_last_update_id = None
        async with websockets.connect(ws_url, ping_interval=None) as websocket:
            await websocket.send(get_subscribe_unsubscribe_str(pair, subscribe_id))
            async for answer in websocket:
                answer_dict = json.loads(answer)
                if 'error' in answer_dict:
                    raise Exception(answer_dict)
                if 'result' in answer_dict:
                    continue
```

Добрый день! Помогите советом пожалуйста. Я хочу хранить большие массивы данных с криптобирж (orderbook).
Но иногда websocket может отвалиться. Как я могу быть уверен что данные получаются всегда и без искажений то есть в каждый промежуток времени. И с помощью какой БД (не postgres) это можно эффективно хранить для частых вызовов?